# What should I look for in a reel for a two handed fly fishing rod?

Tags: fishing-tackle, fly-fishing

I want to buy myself a Shakespeare Oracle 11' #7/8 EXP switch rod to get started in two-handed casting for large-sized local rainbow trout at a wide water body where back room for casting is scarce.

What reel would you recommend? Is any reel made for #7 lines fine? Or do I have to take anything special into account?

Comment: Vote to close as a shopping question. Please look at the help page for asking questions https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: I rewrote your question, because specific product recommendations are off topic and are quickly made obsolete. I also split it to just the reel, the question about the line is worth its own question.